# node.js/express.js hosted on firebase cannot export database and authentication listeners

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have a `node/express` application hosted with firebase functions, which can respond to `GET/POST` requests as expected. However when I try to attach authentication listeners and exporting them, the authentication functions do not fire, even though the express server is still working as expected. My `index.ts`:

```
const server = express();

server.get('/api' , (req : express.Request , res : express.Response ) => {
    res.send("/api endpoint");
})

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(server);


// this even is not triggering
exports.userEvents = functions.auth.user().onCreate( user => {

    spiceAdmin.auth().createUser({
          email         : 'another-user@gmail.com'
        , emailVerified : false
        , password      : 'Sup3rSafe'
    }) 
    .then((userRecord : any) => console.log('created new user'))
    .catch((err : string) => console.log(`failed to create new user with ${err}`))

});
```

And `firebase.json`:

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ]
  },
  "hosting": {

    "public": "public",

    // node/express application
    "rewrites": [{
        "source": "**"
      , "function": "app"  
      }],


    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  }
}
```

Nothing I try seems to be of effect. Has anyone else witnessed this problem?

Comment: Do you see the `userEvents` function in the Cloud Functions tab in the Firebase console? When you deploy, does it deploy the `userEvents` function?

Comment: @Michael Bleigh I am running this on local with Firebase serve. And no I don’t see it. Only app

Comment: Only HTTP functions are capable of being emulated locally with `firebase serve`. You will need to deploy your app for other types of triggers to work.

Comment: @MichaelBleigh if you post the comment in an answer I'll check resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Only HTTP functions are capable of being emulated locally with firebase serve. You will need to deploy your app for other types of triggers to work.